# Send http request in Ionic with Angular http

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, localhost, stripe-payments

I have an ionic app that I am trying to send my `Stripe` token to, for payment processing. When I send the request to the `node` server with `curl` it is receiving the request. However, when I try to send the request via Angular's http module, it isn't registering at all. All of this is currently being tested locally, so that might be part of the issue?

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="testPost()" ion-button full>TEST POST</button>
```

**cart.ts**

```
...
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Stripe } from '@ionic-native/stripe';

@Component({
 selector: 'page-cart',
 templateUrl: 'cart.html',
})
export class Cart {

  constructor(
    ...
    private http: Http,
    private stripe: Stripe
    ) {
      //
    });    
  }

  testPost() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let postParams = {
      body: {
        token: 'axqrexample123tokenbasdflkjo3',
        amount: 225
      }
    }

    this.http.post("http://11.1.1.7:3100/charge", postParams, options)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data['_body']);
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);// Error getting the data
      });  
  }

}
```

**NODE SERVER**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_abcTAdefgn1oDexamplex");

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/charge', function (req, res) {

  var token = req.body.token;
  var amount = req.body.amount;
  stripe.charges.create({
    amount: amount,
    currency: "usd",
    source: token, // obtained with Stripe.js 
    description: "Charge for jones@example.com"
  }, function(err, charge) {
    // asynchronously called
  });
  res.send('Hello World!')
});


app.listen(3100, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3100!')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to map the request before subscribing to the request

```
this.http.post("http://11.1.1.7:3100/charge", postParams, options)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data['_body']);
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);// Error getting the data
      });
```

also, import the `rxjs`

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this in the `stripe.charges.create` callback and see what happens:

```
}, function(err, charge) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('Charge ID:', charge.id); 

  res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

Comment: the error message is coming from `cart.ts`, which won't make the request...it isn't reaching the Node Server. The Node Server itself functions correclty.

Comment: What is the error message?  Your post didn't include an error message.